# Is it true that a C++ compiler is written multiple times for different platforms (Linux, windows etc)

Tags: c++, linux, compiler-construction, cross-compiling, iso

As far as I know C++ is an ISO standard, so they provide some sort of standards and list of features to be implemented for the coming release.

Is it the case that every platform owner will go and write their own implementation for those standards?

Or is there any core compiler code which is implemented once and then every other platform will write wrappers around it?

Or do they write their own C++ compiler from scratch?

Comment: Think of the [GCC](https://gcc.gnu.org/) or [Clang](https://clang.llvm.org/) compilers. They are *portable*, and runs on *multiple platforms*. Rewriting them for each platform would be just stupid, especially since a modern C++ compiler is millions of lines of code. There are however no "standard" or reference implementation. Both GCC and Clang were, initially, written from scratch.

Comment: Most people will use clang or gcc to actually implement C++.  Microsoft has its own compiler and there are other independent ones (Edison design group, etc).  In short, there are a few C++ compilers with totally separate code, but every platform owner won't necessarily write their own.

Comment: Although C++ is an ISO standard, the standard does not cover some binary details like (certain aspects of) memory layout and calling conventions. For example, you can't use a C++ API from a DLL compiled with gcc in a program compiled by Microsoft's C++ compiler on Windows.

Comment: Of course there are well known cross platform compiler like GCC or Clang, but in the end those compiler still implement platform specific code under the hood. E.g. for multithreading or standard output and input they have to use some platform specific features without going into much detail here. The compiler also share code for STL containers for example.

Comment: Probably compilers have some `#ifdef`s with code dependent on the platform, so, when the compiler itself is compiled, its code is sligtly (only slightly) different on different platforms.

Comment: There will be a different memory layouts  for different platforms, but let's say I want to implement lambda (C++11 lambdas) feature then the core of it should not be written multiple times on multiple platforms, This will not ensure the consistency across all the platforms.

Comment: Is it true that diesel engine is developed multiple times for BMW, Mercedes, Toyota, etc. Maybe you think that all manufacturers share exactly the same project, schemes, etc.

Comment: Maybe it should also be mentioned that there is no truly platform independent programming language at all. Even Java or JavaScript is run on a platform specific virtual machine, which usually is written in C++.

Comment: True, it has to be developed once and BMW, Mercedes and other companies will use the same but will add some more features to it but the core will be same

Comment: This is like, your opinion, man.

Answer (score 6):

Yes and no. Compiler basically consists of two parts: parser (a.k.a front-end) and code generator (a.k.a. back-end). Parser is responsible of recogninizing C++ grammar. Code generator constructs machine code for target platform (hardware type and operating system) based on information it gets from parser. While parser is platform independent, code generator part is tied to target platform. So, in order to support a new platform, one can reuse existing parser part, but has to write new code generator part.

Comment: True, but let's say I want to implement lambda (C++11 lambdas) feature then the core of it should not be written multiple times on multiple platforms, This will not ensure the consistency across all the platforms.

Comment: I'd say that depends, if you really want to know maybe look at the actual source code of a well known compiler like GCC. For your specific example lambas I'd guess it's not really platform specific, since lambdas are just anonymous functions and are mostly handled as normal functions from the compiler side. So the basic jump and move instructions should be similar to a function.

Comment: @ChetanKole That's exactly what this answer already says. The parsing, AST, etc remains the same. Only the code generation is per-platform, and it is likely that the AST will reuse existing nodes rather than having to invent new ones, which may mean that no new code-generation implementation is necessary on any platform.

Answer (score 1):

Basically what ISO standards set is set of rules that should be followed by the compiler vendors.
But these are the standards for implementation and not the actual implementation.

Every major hardware vendor knows how to use its own hardware best
This includes aspects like
1) ABI support - This include things like binary formats, system calls and other interfaces
2) Shared Libraries.
3) Architecture Support.

So Microsoft, IBM, Intel, Oracle, and HP all have their own C++ compilers, which create optimal code on their latest hardware.

Standards, however do provide the draft that has to be purchased 
https://isocpp.org/std/the-standard

The following table presents compiler support for new C++ features. These include C++11, C++14, C++17, and later accepted revisions to the standard, as well as various technical specifications.

http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/compiler_support

Answer (score -2):

Likely once they where created platform specific, put simple a windows exe or com file wont run on linux, however later versions can be compiled trough older versions.